# Can we use DeviceAdmin API to handle application specific policies

Tags: android, device-admin

I need to handle expire of password in Android Application.The password will be stored in preferences or db.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html says that DeviceAdmin Api has ability to set policies like "Password expiration timeout"

Is it possible to use this feature to handle application specific credentials ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can. By using DeviceAdmin API we can set/reset password and do more like this as they specified in this api.

To get device admin rights to your application, user has to accept your app as admin at least once.

You can check this by run that sample app which is provided in the link in your question.